# Foundation framework - moving column source order between rows

Tags: zurb-foundation, multiple-columns, rows

I have a Foundation-specific query and hoped you could help. I have a first row of two columns above a second row. I want the second (righ hand) column of the first row to fall beneath the second row in mobile format. I've looked into push/pull etc but I'm having difficulty switching columns between rows. Any ideas how this can be achieved please?

Thanks,
MK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible in the way you describe via Foundation's Push / Pull, as it is to reorder **[columns only](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#source-ordering)** (not rows and columns).

You could reconstruct your HTML to be just one row (this has other associated problems though), and then use Push / Pull

Or (more simply) employ the [Visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html#show-by-screen-size) to show one row for small only and hide it for medium upwards and the other vice versa:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        Top left
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns show-for-medium">
        Top right
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
        Bottom
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns show-for-small-only">
        Bottom for small
    </div>
</div>
```

This example in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/metph67a/).